# fosuserbundle override register form, and use configuration variables

Tags: symfony, parameters, overriding, fosuserbundle

I am overriding the register form and works fine:

```
services.yml
general_user.registration.form.type:
        class: General\GeneralBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: general_user_registration }
```

I have a variable in config.yml I want to access from the RegistrationFormType:

```
# interested in options    
profile.lookingfor: 
    - part 1
    - part 2
```

I read that this can be done using a service, so I defined another one:

```
general_user.registration.form.type.lookingfor:
        class: General\GeneralBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%profile.lookingfor%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: general_user_registration  }
```

I would like to be able to access the parameter from RegistrationFormType using something like:

```
$lookingFor = $this->get('general_user.registration.form.type');
```

I don't know how to mix the 2 services together. Now I get error:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class "General\GeneralBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType".
Did you mean to call e.g. "getBlockPrefix", "getName" or "getParent"?
```

When I comment out the get call I get another error:

```
Cannot read index "email" from object of type "...\CoreBundle\Entity\User" because it doesn't implement \ArrayAccess
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used a Setter Injection. From http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection :

If you have optional dependencies for a class, then "setter injection" may be a better option. This means injecting the dependency using a method call rather than through the constructor. I added a setter method in my RegistrationFormType

```
protected $lookingFor;

    public function setLookingfor($lookingFor) {

        $this->lookingFor = $lookingFor;
    }
```

Injecting the dependency by the setter method just needs adding the 'calls' section:

## app/config/services.yml

```
general_user.registration.form.type:
    class: General\GeneralBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
    arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: general_user_registration }
    calls:
        - [setLookingfor, ['%profile.lookingfor%']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are passing the variable as an argument to your service is only working for parameters (variables defined under `parameters:` in `config.yml` or `parameters.yml`). You don't need the second service in this case.

In order to access it in your service you just have to define a constructor parameter in your service and the argument get's injected automatically as an array.

```
protected $lookingFor;
public function __constructor($lookingFor) {
    $this->lookingFor = $lookingFor;
}
```

If you want to use a config block for your bundle it get's a bit more complicated. See: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html

Comment: I did as you said, but when I try to use the $lookingFor it is null. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you still using two different services or just one?

Comment: just one. but how will the form get the parameter? I don't override the controller.